# Microsoft Bot Framework 4 Emulador devuelve Operation Unauthorized

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-aad

Desde hace días vengo tratando de hacer funcionar este ejemplo de bot Framework 4
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication

Básicamente hay que hacer estos pasos en el azure AD:

1. Ir al directorio activo de azure
2. Registrar la App, y generar un secreto
3. Agregar las siguientes RedirectUri

   - https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect
   - https://api.botframework.com/api/usertoken/
   - https://api.botframework.com/.default
4. Una vez hecho esto, en el bot Service hay que ir a los settings y agregar una nueva Oauth connection string con los datos del directorio activo. Yo la he creado con el nombre `juank` usando una conexión con el Azure AD V2. al probarla desde el mismo portal funciona sin problema.

[image]

5.Luego desde la app de ejemplo, hay que ir al app Settings y modificar estos valores

```
{
  "ConnectionName": "juank",
  "MicrosoftAppId": "cee20ee74c-1b3e-49b4-9e76-b72ee7d74e018d",
  "MicrosoftAppPassword": "W:ydde7bw3t.h1K4.iIqNefLgcl-dfsdf4:.VA]c"
}
```

dsfsdf

6. Luego de esto hay que ejecutar el emulador y configurar los siguientes settings en el endpoint

[image]

7. Hasta ahí todo bien,

[image]

8. Excepto porque sencillamente **no funciona**, cuando doy alguna instrucción para que se muestre el `OAuthPrompt` el bot emulator recibo `Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'` al ingresar cualquier instrucción ( que se supone es lo que hay que hacer para que pida login )

[image]

```
    {
      "type": "trace",
      "timestamp": "2019-12-19T16:47:25.1226799+00:00",
      "serviceUrl": "http://localhost:52755",
      "channelId": "emulator",
      "from": {
        "id": "61bab030-214b-11ea-9cf4-193735472c4b",
        "name": "Bot",
        "role": "bot"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "id": "30652f31-227f-11ea-bb9b-5db534c497ab|livechat"
      },
      "recipient": {
        "id": "4dd2fe7f-f5fd-420b-b3f5-b393f255a14e",
        "name": "User",
        "role": "user"
      },
      "replyToId": "3ab4f470-227f-11ea-9354-f3ab567976d7",
      "label": "TurnError",
      "valueType": "https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error",
      "value": "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'",
      "name": "OnTurnError Trace"
    }
```

Me estoy perdiendo de algo para hacerlo funcionar?es un procedimiento relativamente sencillo pero no encuentro como hacerlo funcionar ni conectando con el emulador al bot local ni al bot remoto.

He logrado adquirir el token desde la herramienta de validación del OAuth setting en el portal en el azure portal y también he usado Postman donde ha funcionado.
Pero no he podido hacer que estos demos funcionen cuando `OAuthPrompt` debe ser presentado para iniciar sesión.

La depuración no ha sido de ayuda ya que no obtengo nada diferente de la información recibida en el JSON mostrado arriba, incluso habilitando la captura de excepciones del framework (First Chance Exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Me pasó exactamente lo mismo. Incluso, descargué el código fuente desde el portal de Azure en ´bot services´ incluyendo la configuración del bot (Debería funcionar).

Tanto haciendolo a mano (clonando el repo y poniendo mi configuración) como con el src del bot descargado daba exactamente el mismo error.

Siendo así, pensé que podría ser problema del emulador...

Revisando la configuración del emulador para el endpoint del bot:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y colocando el AppId y AppSecret aqui:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Funciona :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero allí no estas habiendo autenticación aún, es decir en esta primera parte garantizas que el emulador y el bot usen el mismo app Id & secret, pero no te estas autenticando

Comment: post actualizado y enriquecido con más info cc @camilo-bernal

Comment: @JuanK  El finde juego un ratico con esto y te cuento.